# How to make bootstrap carousel slider slide when the cursor is on the slides

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

How can I make this carousel slider slide even though the mouse cursor is on the images of the slides? The problem is, when I don't drag my cursor to the slides, the slider works normally but when my cursor is on the slides, it stops sliding.

I have updated the carousel's HTML file but now it's not even sliding, I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static 'newsnevents/fuar_image_new.jpeg' %}" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static 'newsnevents/fuar_resimler_devam.jpeg' %}" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static 'newsnevents/fuar_resimler_devam_2.jpeg' %}" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      pause: false,
      interval: 3000

    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: See the [`pause option`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/carousel/#options).

Comment: I need to change the pause option, thanks.